# Является ли курьер с документами протоколом передачи данных?

Tags: теория, протоколы

Моего коллегу Константина начальство послало в соседний корпус с документами, которые он должен отдать.

**Вопрос:** с точки зрения теории информации и других компьютерных наук можем ли мы считать Константина протоколом передачи данных, а окружающий его холод улицы (в процессе движения) - средой распространения информации?

**PS.** Вопрос не ради хохмы, пишу методичку для чайников по информатике.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Конечно же конкретный курьер Константин не является протоколом. И даже абстрактный курьер протоколом не является. Протокол - это не физическая сущность, это описание процесса, обобщенный алгоритм.

Ниже я рассмотрел подробнее как могли бы выглядеть протоколы разных уровней в этом стеке.

---

Физический уровень. Как происходит передача документов курьером?

1. Директор вызывает курьера
2. Директор передаёт документы курьеру
3. Курьер идёт в соседний корпус к получателю документов
4. Курьер передаёт документы получателю
5. Получатель говорит курьеру "спасибо" (или "ну наконец-то") и забирает документы

Попытаемся обобщить этот алгоритм, избавившись от слишком конкретных шагов. Интересно ли получателю то, как директор передавал документы курьеру? Нет, ему интересны только сами документы. Интересно ли директору, как получатель забирал документы? Нет, ему важен только чтобы получатель их получил.

Остаётся от алгоритма следующее: *"курьер берёт документы и идёт с ними к получателю, после чего отдаёт их получателю"*. Это и есть протокол физического уровня.

Что же такое в таком случае курьер в этой аналогии? А курьер тут - среда. То, что переносит информацию.

---

Теперь канальный уровень. Канальный уровень управляет доступом к среде. К протоколу канального уровня относятся алгоритмы вызова курьера, в который надо предусмотреть ситуации *"что делать если курьер занят"* (директор может подождать или назначить курьером кого-то ещё - во втором случае средой передачи станет множество курьеров), *"что делать если курьера пытается отправить не директор, а кто-то ещё"* или *"как курьер узнает получателя"* (да-да, в этом стеке протоколов будущего предусмотрена авторизация на канальном уровне!)

---

Сетевой и транспортный уровни. В вашем примере эти уровни не предусмотрен, поскольку курьер принципиально один. Однако, можно придумать другой пример, в котором один курьер будет передавать документ другому или вообще пойдёт на почту. Это и будет протоколом сетевого уровня. Протокол же транспортного уровня будет отвечать за подтверждение доставки (или не будет, см. UDP)

---

Прикладной уровень. На этом уровне описывается формат передаваемого документа.

Comment: Очень интересно. Наверно лучший ответ из всех.

Answer (score 6):

Нет, не можем.

Протокол, это скорее соглашение о том, что информация передаётся таким-то способом.
Соглашение о том, что документы пересылаются курьерами - это протокол. Ваш Константин его конкретная реализация (одна из возможных). Улица -  среда. Холод - один из параметров среды.

Как-то так...

Comment: А чем не соглашение? Ведь отдел разработки и отдел контроля согласились, что Константин будет носить документы.

Comment: Курьер - это "железная реализация" протокола. В былые времена его заменяли голуби, всадники на конях итд.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin имеется в виду, что реализация протокола "в железе" не есть сам протокол. Курьер - одна из субстанций, которая носит пакеты с документами через среду. Его может заменить например вакуумная почта, или даже квадракоптеры...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич что-то начинает доходить, что похоже вы правы. Но посмотрим ответы других экспертов.

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать модель OSI, то

1. Физический уровень (то, где перемещается курьер) город, область, Вселенная
2. Канальный (откуда и куда) Улица, здание или кабинет
3. Сетевой (способ перемещения пакета данных) Курьер
4. Транспортный (надёжность и скорость доставки) Его портфель
5. Сеансовый (возьми это и отдай туда, мне доложи) Секретарша
6. Представительский (секретный документ в конверт и в отправку) Директор
7. Прикладной (я сделаю документ, а дальше отправляйте куда хотите) Главбух

Comment: Так да или нет? Костик - is communication protocol or no?

Comment: Это философский вопрос, вне области IT и точных наук

Answer (score 1):

Протокол (любого уровня) - это способ передачи данных, в том числе способ с применением Константина. Если Константин придерживается ряда строгих правил и его участие в процессе обмена согласовано как передающей, так и принимающей стороной - его *можно* считать протоколом.

В разрезе модели OSI курьер Константин, конечно же, выполняет свои функции на уровне **транспортного** протокола, а именно - обеспечивает надёжную передачу данных от отправителя к получателю.

Рассмотрим всю цепочку обмена:

Представим, что некая секретарша (которая, конечно же, работает на уровне **представления**) заботливо запечатывает данные, полученные от **прикладного** уровня в виде руководства (отчёты, денежные средства, договоры и пр.) в конверт, а затем передаёт их в качестве поручения Константину, с которым она предварительно познакомилась и возможно, даже планирует поддерживать длительные дружеские отношения до тех пор, пока он работает в Компании (так сказать, на **сеансовом** уровне).

Костик совершенно не в курсе о назначении передаваемых им сообщений, но его это и не интересует. Он заворачивает их в своё пальто, чтобы пакет с доносами и кляузами на коллег не промок и не принял непристойный вид в результате попадания под проливной питерский дождь). И извлечёт Константин этот пакет не раньше, чем войдёт в сухое и теплое помещение пункта назначения,  уж будьте уверены.

Нет, его конечно могут принудительно заставить раздеться и даже пройти досмотр на входе в метро, но вот внутрь конверта ни у кого по пути заглянуть не получится - ведь документы надежно запечатаны, и распечатать их можно, лишь разорвав конверт.

В процессе совершения доставки он пользуется подсказками о координатах конечного пункта, которые содержатся на **сетевом** в виде набора адресов, каждый из которых присвоен отдельному зданию или кабинету. Если Константин перед отправлением не выяснил точное месторасположение пункта назначения, ему придётся буквально уткнуться ("завернуться") в карту района и следуя по пути, постоянно сверяться с её содержимым.

Константину свойственны и некоторые типичные проблемы транспортного уровня:

Его надежность находится под вопросом: для подтверждения факта успешной доставки им данных в конечный пункт может потребоваться подтверждение. Но зачастую из-за высоких накладных расходов на такие подтверждения в компаниях кладут болт, ведь доля потерянных Константинов в течение рабочего дня обычно незначительна.

Гарантирует ли Константин правильную последовательность получения адресатом отправленных данных?
Разумеется, да. Как правило, следующее поручение Константину будет выдано лишь после возвращения его в исходный пункт. В случае внезапной пропажи Константина налаженный механизм обмена документами в Компании прервётся, но не надолго. Обворожительной секретарше придётся вновь составить поручение, но уже передать его другому курьеру. И процесс обмена будет запущен вновь.

Замечу ещё, что весь городской транспорт, тротуары, коридоры, а также прочая **канальная** инфраструктура доступного для доставки сегмента (города, района или кампуса крупной компании), по которой возможно перемещение Константина, используются им в процессе доставки данных. В их числе, кстати могут оказаться и мосты ;) которые в модели OSI работают как раз-таки на канальном уровне.

Что же является низшим, **физическим** протоколом в этом случае? Ни воздух, ни город, ни сама по себе Вселенная сигналы не распространяют, то есть средой они конечно являются, а вот протоколом физического уровня - нет. А протоколом я бы назвал физическое перемещение от отправителя к адресату, ведь именно этот процесс лежит в основе передачи информации.

Итак, резюмирую - передача сообщений с помощью Константина - это явный пример использования курьер-подобного протокола обмена.